# Do while loop in JavaScript stops looping when condition is not met

Tags: javascript, do-while

I wrote a do while loop but it does not keep looping even though the condition is not met. There in an array called quotes and I am comparing the input number to the length of that array to make sure it only modifies an element already there. Even though I add a higher number, it just adds it to that array element.

```
function modifyQuote(){
    'use strict'

    var modifyQuoteNum = 0
    do{
        var inputModify = prompt("what quote do you want to modify?");
        modifyQuoteNum = (parseInt(inputModify) - 1); 
    }
    while ((typeof modifyQuoteNum == 'number') && 
        ((modifyQuoteNum + 1) <= quotes.length));
```

Figured it out, got mixed up.

```
function modifyQuote(){
    'use strict'

    var inputModify = prompt("what quote do you want to modify?");
    var modifyQuoteNum = (parseInt(inputModify) - 1);

    while ((typeof modifyQuoteNum != 'number') || 
        ((modifyQuoteNum + 1) > quotes.length)){

        var inputModify = prompt("what quote do you want to modify?");
        var modifyQuoteNum = (parseInt(inputModify) - 1);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got your condition the wrong way round.

> it does not keep looping even though the condition is **not** met

That's how `while` loops work: they only keep looping while the condition **is** met.

The fix is trivial, so I'll let you figure out what it is as an exercise.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean.